# Having array identifiers on the end of a function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some some problems here. I am using XAMPP on a Windows box to test. I will be uploading the final product to a CentOS server.

I have this line of code:

```
$dbFunc->GetTemplateName($report['uat_template'])[0]['uat_name'];
```

On the Windows configuration, this works fine. However I get a parse error on the Unix box. It isn't happy with the `[0]` identifier.

If i do;

```
$temp = $dbFunc->GetTemplateName($report['uat_template']);
$temp = $temp[0];
echo $temp['uat_name'];
```

It works fine, but it's added 2 lines of code?

Is there any way to make the first way work on Unix?

Thanks

Comment: what are the PHP versions u have on WIN and on LINUX ?

Comment: Check your php version on the CentOS server. The use of index access directly on a function return was allowed on 5.4 I think

Comment: Yes from V - 5.4 its supported !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example in your question makes use of array dereferencing feature in PHP, which is only available for PHP 5.4+. If you're using an older PHP version, you will need to upgrade. If upgrading is not an option, you're stuck with the second method, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.4 PHP added a function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].
So it looks like on CentOS you have >=PHP5.4 and on XAMPP <5.4

More info : http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php